# How does Sledgehammer translate lambda-abstractions to ATPs?

Tags: isabelle

In *Extending Sledgehammer with SMT solvers* there is this claim:

> Lambda-abstractions are rewritten to Turner combinators or transformed into explicit functions using lambda-abstractions.

The linked reference, *Translating higher-order clauses to first-order clauses* does not clarify how are this method synchronized. Do we use both of them always? Is one preferred to the other?

Comment: Does Jasmin Blanchette's thesis https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1097834/1097834.pdf  Section 6.4.2 help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1097834/1097834.pdf the choice of method is tailored for each prover.